# is It faster to insert rows in primary key order?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

```
create table stream_last
(
        symbol_id       integer,
        high            decimal(8,2),
        low             decimal(8,2),
        last            decimal(8,2),
        volume          integer,
        last_updated    datetime,
        INDEX USING BTREE(symbol_id)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

I need to do about 4,000 inserts every 5 seconds (blasted in by a C program reading a stream and aggregating on symbol_id).  However, I could sort the data first and insert in order by symbol_id ASCENDING.  would that make this bulk insert faster?

a secondary question would be, is BTREE the best option here for index?  From the documentation, I could have used HASH but wasn't sure which would be best...

Don

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think you may gain any significant difference with the optimisation you've proposed, but advises listed here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

may certainly help you understand better your needs.

This quote may have sense

> The size of the table slows down the insertion of indexes by log N,
>   assuming B-tree indexes.
>
> You can use the following methods to speed up inserts:
>
> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements. If you are
>   adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the
>   bulk_insert_buffer_size variable to make data insertion even faster.
>   See Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”.

Comment: wow no kidding.  thx for info.  I was unaware of this : INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Answer (score 1):

These docs suggest that inserting in primary key order will give you a performance improvement:

> When performing bulk inserts, it is faster to insert rows in PRIMARY KEY order. InnoDB tables use a clustered index, which makes it relatively fast to use data in the order of the PRIMARY KEY. Performing bulk inserts in PRIMARY KEY order is particularly important for tables that do not fit entirely within the buffer pool.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

It will be best to combine this optimization with the bulk insert statement referenced in @Igor's answer.