# Insert multiple values via PHP PDO into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert 20 values at once **via PHP Data Objects**. At the moment I'm doing it this way, it seems *very ugly*:

```
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO <tablename> (`uid`, `mid`, `status`) 
                                VALUES  (:uid, :mid1, :status), (:uid, :mid2, :status), 
                                        (:uid, :mid3, :status), (:uid, :mid4, :status),
                                        (:uid, :mid5, :status), ... and so on ...");
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $this->uid);

    $random_mid = array_rand(range(1,20), 5);

    $ref = new Mooney($random_mid[0]);
    $myMid1 = $ref->getMid();
    $stmt->bindParam(':mid1', $myMid1);

    $ref = new Mooney($random_mid[1]);
    $myMid2 = $ref->getMid();
    $stmt->bindParam(':mid2', $myMid2);

    $ref = new Mooney($random_mid[2]);
    $myMid3 = $ref->getMid();
    $stmt->bindParam(':mid3', $myMid3);

    ... and so on ...

    $status = 'open'; // default starting value of status
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Is there a better solution by using a for-loop or so? Hope you can provide a better solution / more beautiful solution. Thanks for your time and help!

**EDIT 1**: Now thanks to **@Jurik** the code works and look like this:

```
private function insertValuesAtOnce() {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `<tablename>` (`uid`, `mid`, `status`) VALUES  (:UID, :MID, :STATUS)');
    $random_mid = $this->UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1, 20, 7);
    require_once('<some path>');
    $status = 'open';
    foreach($random_mid AS $val){
        $ref = new Mooney($val);
        $myMid = $ref->getMid();

        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':UID' => $this->uid,
            ':MID' => $myMid,
            ':STATUS' => $status
        ));
    }
}
```

But it seems to me, that this is not a "insert many rows at once" but more "insert a single row multiple times"

**EDIT 2:** Because it does not seem to be possible to insert all values at once, I will use the solution to insert them row by row, but wrapping it into a transaction! This improved the runtime from  0,3915548324585 sec/serialize to  0,074591159820557 sec/serialize.

```
private function insertValuesAtOnce() {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `<tablename>` (`uid`, `mid`, `status`) VALUES  (:UID, :MID, :STATUS)');
    $random_mid = $this->UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1, 20, 7);
    require_once('<some path>');
    $status = 'open';

    // Beginn Transaction (ACID)     
    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

    foreach($random_mid AS $val){
        $ref = new Mooney($val);
        $myMid = $ref->getMid();

        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':UID' => $this->uid,
            ':MID' => $myMid,
            ':STATUS' => $status
        ));
    }
    // End Transaction (ACID)
    $this->pdo->commit();
}
```

Comment: Question is why do you want insert them at once? Because your `getMid()` gets data from database that needs a data base **before** anything else inserts into db?

Comment: Fixed performance by using Transactions!

Comment: Multiple inserets at once would still be nice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219980/is-it-faster-to-insert-rows-in-primary-key-order

Comment: Ack, sorry - copy&paste mistake, I forgott `beginTransaction`. Otherwise `commit` doesn't make sense. Don't forgett `rollback` on db error. So you won't have inconsistent data. Good job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php  
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');
  $query = $db->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `user_mooney` (`uid`, `mid`, `status`)
    VALUES  (:UID, :MID, :STATUS)'
  );

  foreach($random_mid AS $val){
    $ref = new Mooney($val);
    $myMid = $ref->getMid();

    $query->execute(array(
      ':UID' => $uid,
      ':MID' => $myMid,
      ':STATUS' => $status
    ));
  }

  $query->commit();
```

If commit throws an error you can call `$query->rollback();` So you've a consist database.

**Edit: took correct answer from question edit 2**

```
<?php  
    private function insertValuesAtOnce() {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `<tablename>` (`uid`, `mid`, `status`) VALUES  (:UID, :MID, :STATUS)');
        $random_mid = $this->UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1, 20, 7);
        require_once('<some path>');
        $status = 'open';

        // Beginn Transaction (ACID)     
        $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

        foreach($random_mid AS $val){
            $ref = new Mooney($val);
            $myMid = $ref->getMid();

            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':UID' => $this->uid,
                ':MID' => $myMid,
                ':STATUS' => $status
            ));
        }
        // End Transaction (ACID)
        $this->pdo->commit();
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. As I understand the code, it does insert the values one after the other and therefore **not at once** as I asked for? Am I right? Thank you anyway very much!

Comment: Well, it prepares the insert one by one and if you want, you could lock the database before you start this insert. Or you create first an array of all those arrays in `$query->execute` and then put this array into execute. So you've all values prepared, before you do the first insert.

Comment: Updated answer - but I'm not sure if this is possible, try it and it will fit to your question.

Comment: Not working, we got a PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens